# If statement inside foreach loop

Tags: php

I'm creating a little booking system. Rows are set to current week columns to a specific time.

What I'm trying to do is to change day names to a specific colour. Blue in the past, date current in green. Somehow the `if` statement isn't doing anything. Could anyone explain or point me in the right direction?

```
$today = time();

$lastWeek = [];
$lastWeek[0] = date('D',strtotime('last monday'));
$lastWeek[1] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +1day'));
$lastWeek[2] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +2day'));
$lastWeek[3] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +3day'));
$lastWeek[4] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +4day'));

$timeSlot = [];
$timeSlot [0] = date('H:i', strtotime('9:00'))      ."-9:30";
$timeSlot [1] = date('H:i', strtotime('9:30'))      ."-10:00";
$timeSlot [2] = date('H:i', strtotime('10:00'))     ."-10:30";
$timeSlot [3] = date('H:i', strtotime('10:30'))     ."-11:00";
$timeSlot [4] = date('H:i', strtotime('11:00'))     ."-11:30";
$timeSlot [5] = date('H:i', strtotime('11:30'))     ."-12:00";

echo "<html><head><title>Doctor Booking timetable</title></head>";
echo "<body><table id=myTable border=2 align=center >";

echo "<tr><td>Week Commencing</td>";

foreach ($timeSlot as $time)
{
    echo"<td>";
    echo $time;
    echo"</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";

foreach ($lastWeek as $day)
{
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $day;
    echo "</td></tr>";
}

if ($lastWeek < $today){
    echo "<font color='blue'></font>";
}else {
    echo "<font color='green'></font>";
}
```

Comment: The `if` statement is *not* inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: you need to look up some HTML tutorials too, your html is invalid. `$lastWeek` is an array it wont evaluate as true

Comment: what is the syntax for if statement inside foreach loop? was getting many errors. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `if` statement inside the `foreach` (like your post title suggests) and also wrap `$day` inside your colour tags. FYI the `font` tag has been deprecated for a long time and you should use `span` instead.

In your question, you are comparing `$lastWeek` with `$today` - `$lastWeek` is an array, which you are looping through. As per your `foreach`, the current iteration will be contained in the `$day` variable, so you should compare **that** to `$today`:

```
foreach ($lastWeek as $day)
{
    echo "<tr><td>";
    $color = ($day < $today) ? 'blue' : 'green';
    echo '<span style="color: ' . $color . '">' . $day . '</span>';
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

PS: I've used the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) here for your if statement. It's the same thing as writing:

```
if($day < $today)
    $color = 'blue';
else
    $color = 'green';
```

... but shorter

PPS. I'm assuming here that your dates are in the correct format to compare using a GT/LT operator. If they aren't, you'll need to format them using something like the [date function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: The OP is also comparing the current timestamp, `$today`, with the array, `$lastWeek`, instead of with the array element, `$day`. You seemed to have corrected this oversight but should probably also explain that specifically.

Comment: thanks for help that's sorted my problem, I also keep in mind what u said about the dates.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the deprecated  tag unless it was very much needed.
See about this in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Using your code style:

```
$today = time();

$lastWeek = array();
$lastWeek[0] = date('D',strtotime('last monday'));
$lastWeek[1] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +1day'));
$lastWeek[2] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +2day'));
$lastWeek[3] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +3day'));
$lastWeek[4] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +4day'));

$timeSlot = array();
$timeSlot [0] = date('H:i', strtotime('9:00'))      ."-9:30";
$timeSlot [1] = date('H:i', strtotime('9:30'))      ."-10:00";
$timeSlot [2] = date('H:i', strtotime('10:00'))     ."-10:30";
$timeSlot [3] = date('H:i', strtotime('10:30'))     ."-11:00";
$timeSlot [4] = date('H:i', strtotime('11:00'))     ."-11:30";
$timeSlot [5] = date('H:i', strtotime('11:30'))     ."-12:00";

echo "<html><head><title>Doctor Booking timetable</title></head>";
echo "<body><table id=myTable border=2 align=center >";

echo "<tr><td>Week Commencing</td>";

foreach ($timeSlot as $time)
{
    echo"<td>";
    echo $time;
    echo"</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";

foreach ($lastWeek as $day)
{
    echo "<tr><td>";
    if ($lastWeek < $today){
        echo "<font color='blue'>$day</font>";
    }else {
        echo "<font color='green'>$day</font>";
    }
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```