# If Statement inside Foreach PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I have code that is pulling an array from a txt file, it is removing columns I do not need and inserting it into a csv file.

The code I am using is removing the columns, but I want it to check two columns, if one is blank, then remove it and use the next column.

It is not looping per row according to if column 12 is blank or not, it basically just runs the if statement once for the first row and applies it to every row.

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($f_in, 8000, "|")) {
    $columns = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]; //index of columns
    if (empty($columns['12'])) {
        $unwanted = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]; //index of unwanted columns
        foreach($unwanted as $i) {
            unset($data[$i]);
        }
    } else {
        $unwanted = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]; //index of unwanted columns
        foreach($unwanted as $i) {
            unset($data[$i]);
        }
    }
    fputcsv($f_out, $data, ',', '"');
```

I get the same results with, not looping for each row.

```
    if ($columns['12'] > 0)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to use `$data[12]`? `$columns ` is that other array you just created in the previous line, so its index 12 will never be empty.

Comment: That did it. I was so close.  $columns = is not need then. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If statement inside foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222898/if-statement-inside-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cleaner solution to your problem:
you basically want to have two items in the result csv base of emptiness of 13th column of each row ($data[12] is pointing to column 13 as array start count from element 0).

so no need to do all tha looping, rather just create array you need from two array elements and push them.

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($f_in, 8000, "|")) {
    if (empty($data[12])) {
        $result = [$data[0],$data[13]];
    } else {
        $result = [$data[0],$data[12]];
    }
    fputcsv($f_out, $result, ',', '"');
```

p.s. if you miscalculated yourself and actually did not want first column of the original item check indexes and remove $data[0] from $result array.

you can also write it like this, and be fancy :)

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($f_in, 8000, "|")) {

    $result = empty($data[12]) ? [$data[0],$data[13]] : [$data[0],$data[12]]; 

    fputcsv($f_out, $result, ',', '"');
```